# How to "group by" or "select" to clean duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

Look the following data:

```
who code  info
1   1467  1
1   1468  2 
1   1469  3 
3   1467  5 
3   1468  4
3   1469  7
```

What I need to do, is to select the codes without duplicates for: WHO=1, how to ignore WHO=3 BUT without say: WHERE who != 3, because I need to do something like:

```
GROUP BY code
```

Actually I get a result like this:

```
1   1468  2 
3   1467  5 
3   1469  7
```

What I want is:

```
1   1467  1
1   1468  2 
1   1469  3
```

Comment: @user975718, can you please clarify more on your question. From what you want, I think a simple SELECT query should suffice: `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE code = 1`. What makes you think that you need a GROUP BY CODE?

Comment: did a mistake in my previous comment; the query should instead say `WHERE who = 1`. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `who` to the group and then use `WHERE` to filter out id 3.

```
SELECT who, code, info FROM data WHERE who != 3 GROUP BY who, code
```

Note that if you select something like `info` from this query without grouping by it, MySQL will give you the value of any one of the rows in the group (with no guarantee about which one -- and that's only if you're using MySQL; most database engines won't even let you construct a query like that!). So what you may want is all three:

```
SELECT who, code, info FROM data WHERE who != 3 GROUP BY who, code, info
```

Comment: what is the use of `GROUP BY` if you are using all 3 field in `GROUP BY` itself??

Comment: @FahimParkar, to select distinct rows. For example, if there are two rows that have "who, code, info" of "1, 1467, 1", it would still only return one row. Since the OP said "without duplicates" I figured this is what they meant.